# Limit taxonomy results to a single cpt

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have two cpt's, events and reports, they both share the taxonomy locations, I have my taxonomy-locations.php, but that is showing reports & events for location, I just want to show reports for location. Can someone help me out with how this query should go?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the loop in your `taxonomy-locations.php` file,

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => 'report' ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

You could, alternatively, modify the query using an appropriate hook (this would be the most effecient method) - but since it is run for most queries, you would need to check it's actually a query for which you want to set post type to 'report'. For example:

```
function my_restrict_to_report() {
    //And any other checks
    if (!is_admin() && is_tax('location')) {
        set_query_var('post_type','report');
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_restrict_to_report' );
```

*Not tested*

Comment: Thanks Stephen, perfect timing as I was just asked to show the site in its current status.

Comment: nice job remembering the is_admin() check

Comment: @helgatheviking I'm not sure it's necessary - I think `is_tax` covers it, but better safe than sorry I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can also do this via the pre_get_posts action.  the $query variable is the entire query object and it is passed 'by reference' meaning that anything you do to it inside the function will modify the original query

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'kia_limit_tax' );

function kia_limit_tax( $query ) {
    //check that we're in the locations taxonomy before modifying the query
    if(is_tax('locations')){
        set_query_var('post_type','event');
            //which is the more elegant way to write this:
            //$query->set('post_type','event');
    }
}
```

is_taxonomy() is deprecated and is_tax() should be used
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax

Comment: Good point about the `set_query_var`. `is_taxonomy` is depreciated though, and returns true if 'locations' exists as a taxonomy, not if the locations archive page is being displayed.

Comment: really?  that's a bummer.  how are you supposed to do it now then?  there is clearly a difference between whether a tax exists and whether you are on that tax's archive.. to taxonomy_exists() doesn't seem right

Comment: [`is_tax`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) checks if its the taxonomy's archive page.

Comment: yup, just found that myself. will correct.