# Custom post type category link + add to menu

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, menus, taxonomy

I am currently developing my own travel website/blog. I would like to add "hotels" and "tips and tricks" to this website. I have made two custom post types that use the default post categories as a taxonomy (as shown below). I haven't bothered making custom taxonomies, as it would triple my work load, since I would just have to copy all the data from the default categories.

```
register_post_type('hotels', 
        array(  'taxonomies'            => array('category'),
                'labels'                => array(
                    'name'                  => __('Hotels'),
                    'singular_name'         => __('Hotel'),
                    'add_new'               => __('Add new hotel'),
                    'edit_item'             => __('Edit hotel'),
                    'new_item'              => __('New hotel'),
                    'view_item'             => __('View hotel'),
                    'search_items'          => __('Search hotels'),
                    'not_found'             => __('No hotels found'),
                    'not_found_in_trash'    => __('No hotels found in trash')
                ),

                'has_archive'           => true,
                'hierarchical'          => true,
                'public'                => true,
                'supports'              => array('title', 'editor', 'post-formats')
    ));
```

Now, there are two things that I can't seem to achieve.

1. Get the link of a category (for example: Mexico) that only shows a custom post type and not my default posts. (e.g. I would want to see the hotels in Mexico)
2. Get an option in the admin-section (menu) that allows me to add said link to the menu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't see your taxonomy, check under the Screen Options tab in the upper-right corner of the admin window and make sure the Show on screen check box is ticked for that taxonomy.

Comment: I am not using a custom taxonomy, taht's the entire thing. I am using the default category taxonomy that is also used in posts. The data for my categories and my custom taxonomies would be entirely the same, so I am trying to use just the default category taxonomy. The only issue I'm facing there, is that I can't get the category page for the custom post types, only for default posts.

Comment: Have you checked out https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43395/limit-taxonomy-results-to-a-single-cpt?

Answer (score 0):

try this, I believe this should allow you to have `category` taxonomy in menu and available in your `custom post type`.

```
function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Post Types', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'hotel', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Post Types', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'hotel', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'post-formats' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'hotels', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```